# Query regarding filtering of table,a table without duplicates is needed

Tags: mysql

How will I write a query which will not give me duplicates using mysql? My result table shouldn't contain duplicates.

the first query is:

```
SELECT ord_no,name, mobile, address,  rate, mrp,
       create_date, edited_date,status
FROM orders o, customer c
where o.cust_id = c.id and status = 'CHECKED' 
  AND DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), edited_date) between 2 and 3 
order by 1;
```

the second query is:

```
SELECT ord_no,name, mobile, address,  rate, mrp, 
      create_date, edited_date,status
FROM orders o, customer c
where o.cust_id = c.id and status = 'CHECKED' 
  AND edited_date<DATE_SUB(now(),interval 48 hour) 
order by 1;
```

How do I filter it?

Comment: Yes but not getting the result as per the requirement

Comment: In this case, it seems like the rows are not duplicates, you will need to use `GROUP BY` with aggregate functions to filter them. Can you please show some sample data and the required results you want to get?

Comment: i want to display  table with edited_date between 48 to 72 hrs.i want to display another table with edited_date between 40 to 72 hrs,but this table shouldnt contain duplicates of the first table .

Comment: Please edit your question and show some sample data from that table just 4 or 5 rows of dummy data and the required results so that we can understand your problem. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try GROUP BY

```
SELECT ord_no,name, mobile, address,  rate, mrp,
   create_date, edited_date,status
FROM orders o, customer c
where o.cust_id = c.id and status = 'CHECKED' 
AND DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), edited_date) between 2 and 3
 GROUP BY ord_no,name, mobile, address,  rate, mrp,
   create_date, edited_date,status 
order by 1;
```

Can you specify if its a certain field you want to be unique? Otherwise this should work.